# URI for using Java Spring Tags

Tags: java, spring-mvc, taglib

Inorder to use Spring Form Tags in JSP file following is taglib element I added :-

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

And I used [this](http://vaannila.com/spring/spring-simple-form-controller-1.html) reference for the same.

However, Eclipse is not able to find the Tag Library Desciptor file. What is the correct URI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The uri is correct.

**Make sure**:

- You have the Eclipse plugin Web Tools Project (WTP) installed
- You have all the Spring jars in your build path
- That the project has the facet "Dynamic Web Module" (go to Project Facets)
- Make sure that it is a JSP file and not a JSPX

If its JSPX the notation would look more like:

```
<html xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
      xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
      xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util">
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds correct. Something like:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

should work. Are you sure you have spring-webmvc jar on your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you have some form of **Spring Servlet** jar in your eclipse classpath. Name should be like `org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.M1` if you are using Spring 3, this should be present under your dist folder in Spring distribution or else `spring-webmvc.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Your Page directive is correct

`<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>`

but make sure that you correctly use the form tag and there should be no space between <form:form ...> or <form:input ...>

***Below code is incorrect:-***

```
<form: form action="InsertDepartment" meathod="post" modelAttribute="department">
            Enter Department No:
            <form: input path="deptno" /><br>
            Enter Department Name:
            <form: input path="dname" /> <br>
            Enter Department Location:
            <form: input path="loc" /><br>

            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />

        </form: form>
```

***Correct Code:-***

```
<form:form action="InsertDepartment" meathod="post" modelAttribute="department">
            Enter Department No:
            <form:input path="deptno" /><br>
            Enter Department Name:
            <form:input path="dname" /> <br>
            Enter Department Location:
            <form:input path="loc" /><br>

            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />

        </form:form>
```